# How to replace strings by retaining certain values in notepad++ using regex?

Tags: replace, find, notepad++

I have string like

```
(1,123,'2016-04-0500:00:01','V1')
(2,123,'2016-04-0500:00:02','V2')
(3,123,'2016-04-0500:00:03','V3')
(4,123,'2016-04-0500:00:04','V4')
(5,123,'2016-04-0500:00:05','V5')
```

And i want to convert like

```
(1,123,['2016-04-0500:00:01',mystring],'V1')
(2,123,['2016-04-0500:00:02',mystring],'V2')
(3,123,['2016-04-0500:00:03',mystring],'V3')
(4,123,['2016-04-0500:00:04',mystring],'V4')
(5,123,['2016-04-0500:00:05',mystring],'V5')
```

When i tried **find** `('2016-04-0500:00:.*?')` and replace with `mytext`. Entire text is getting replaced, i coudn't retain `00:00:01,00:00:02...` . Can somebody help here. There may some simple trick but i couldn't find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Ctrl+H for the replace tab
- Tick *Regular expression*
- Find: **`('.*')`**
- Replace With: **`[\1,mystring]`**

(Matches within `()` are captured and can be referenced later as `\1`)